# convert to pdf while saving

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a django nodel. and in django admin when i fill it and click save button, it be saved in django admin and also it should be converted and saved as a pdf file. how to do this? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method that listens on the [post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/) for your model; then you can follow the tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/outputting-pdf/) on how to output PDFs from django.

If your PDF layout is simple, you can use the [xhtml2pdf](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/) library to convert a HTML template to a PDF file.